# How do I rename values within a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I am attempting to rename values within my data frame "meansleep"

I have columns "Id"
within the Id columns I have 22 values and I am attempting to rename these values to "sleepy1", "sleepy2", "sleepy3", ...

I am using function `meansleep$Id\[c(1:22)\] \<- c('sleepy1', 'sleepy2', ...)`

Is there a way to run this function without retyping all the sleepyvalues.. for instance to correlate `c(1:22)` to `c('sleepy1':'sleepy22')`

Thank you

Comment: Those backslashes shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

```
meansleep$Id <- paste0('sleepy', 1:21)
```